# RISC-V: How to fix "file format not recognized" when disassembling a .img file?

Tags: objdump, riscv32

I'm playing with RISC-V.
I have a .img file and I want to disassemble it into a .asm file, so I ran the following command:

```
> riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -d xxx.img > xxx.asm
```

However, I got this issue:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump: xxx.img: file format not recognized
```

How can I fix it? I have no idea what to do with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you run:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump --help
```

You'll see a line like:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump: supported architectures: riscv riscv:rv64 riscv:rv32
```

These are the supported architectures that you need to pass as the `-m` argument. Normally, an ELF file will encode this information so there's no guesswork, but in the case of using a flat file, there's no way for `objdump` to know how the instructions are supposed to be interpreted. The final command is:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -b binary -m riscv:rv64 -D xxx.bin
```